# else no if boolean error

Tags: java, boolean

Wondering if someone could help see why this is returning an error on there being an else without an if. I have tried looking at other questions to no avail

```
public boolean isLate()   {
if( done = false); AND (deadline.hasPassed = true);   {
return true;
} else{
    return false;}
}
```

Comment: Learn some basic java coding

Comment: I think you need to learn some basic Java like: Condition operator, Comparation... Some links to refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 5):

`AND` is not correct. It must be replaced by `&&` and move inside the `ìf` definition. Moreover use `==` to compare instead of `=`

```
if(done == false && deadline.hasPassed == true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Because `done` and `deadline.hasPassed` seem to be booleans, you can simplify it writting (`!` means `not`)

```
if(!done && deadline.hasPassed) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Which can be simplify as

```
public boolean isLate()   {
    return !done && deadline.hasPassed;
}
```

Comment: It's not good to provide the answers directly, OP will not learn anything by this.

Comment: There's no need for a conditional branch here!

Comment: Definitely, but the initial problem was about the `if` so I keep it in my answer. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are looking for is:

```
public boolean isLate() {
    return ((done == false) && (deadline.hasPassed == true));
}
```

But this kind of basic understanding in java can be googled!